# Understanding ruby TOPLEVEL_BINDING

Tags: ruby, rack

I understand that TOPLEVEL_BINDING is the Binding object for main. The following code confirms it:

```
def name
  :outer
end

module Test
  class Binder
    def self.name
      :inner
    end

    def self.test_it
      eval 'name', TOPLEVEL_BINDING
    end
  end
end

p Test::Binder.test_it # => :outer
```

I got confused while looking at the source for rack. The problem was in understanding this code in the file `lib/rack/builder.rb`

```
def self.new_from_string(builder_script, file="(rackup)")
  eval "Rack::Builder.new {\n" + builder_script + "\n}.to_app",
    TOPLEVEL_BINDING, file, 0
end

def run(app)
end
```

The new_from_string method is passed the contents of a config.ru file which will be something like

```
run DemoApp::Application
```

Here it seems like TOPLEVEL_BINDING is referring to a Builder object, since the method `run` is defined for Builder but not for Object. However the earlier experiment establishes that TOPLEVEL_BINDING refers to main's binding. I do not understand how run method is working here. Please help me in understanding this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TOPLEVEL_BINDING` *is* the top level binding.

That method is passing the string "run ..." into `Builder.new { run ... }`

Builder.new then does an instance_eval (https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/df1506b0825a096514fcb3821563bf9e8fd52743/lib/rack/builder.rb#L53-L55) on the block, thereby giving the code inside the block direct access to the instance's methods.

```
def initialize(default_app = nil,&block)
  @use, @map, @run, @warmup = [], nil, default_app, nil
  instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
end
```

`run` is an instance method of the Builder class, defined here -> https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/df1506b0825a096514fcb3821563bf9e8fd52743/lib/rack/builder.rb#L103-L105

```
def run(app)
  @run = app
end
```

In short, `"run DemoApp::Application"` becomes:

```
Rack::Builder.new {
  run DemoApp::Application
}.to_app
```

Edit: A simple example to illustrate the point:

```
class Builder
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def run(what)
    puts "Running #{what}"
  end
end

TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval "Builder.new { run 10 }"
```

prints

```
Running 10
```

Comment: The thing is you get "Running 10" with or without `TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval`. It sort of looks like `rack` developers are trying to provide clean environment for the app, but if I was asked what can go wrong otherwise... I've got no answer for that. And you?

Answer (score 0):

`TOPLEVEL_BINDING` gives you access to [context](https://ruby-doc.com/core/Binding.html) in which the first file was executed:

`a.rb`:

```rb
a = 1
p TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variables  #=> [:a]
require_relative 'b'
```

`b.rb`:

```rb
b = 1
p TOPLEVEL_BINDING.local_variables  #=> [:a]
```

```
$ ruby a.rb
```

What `rack` developers are apparently trying to achieve is to isolate the builder line/script from all what is accessible from `Rack::Builder.new_from_string` (local variables, methods, you name it).

There's also a comment there [these days](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/v3.0.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb#L97-L106):

```
    # Evaluate the given +builder_script+ string in the context of
    # a Rack::Builder block, returning a Rack application.
    def self.new_from_string(builder_script, file = "(rackup)")
      # We want to build a variant of TOPLEVEL_BINDING with self as a Rack::Builder instance.
      # We cannot use instance_eval(String) as that would resolve constants differently.
      binding, builder = TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval('Rack::Builder.new.instance_eval { [binding, self] }')
      eval builder_script, binding, file

      return builder.to_app
    end
```